# Filtering across multiple indices using ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is is possible to write a conditional filter on an Elasticsearch multi-index query?

I am looking at the filter script, but I can't see anywhere in the documentation if the documents index is a variable I can check?

My existing query looks like this, note the filter script doesn't work - but I assume this is where I need to do my query.

```
{
    "index": "tweets,articles,animals,buildings",
    "type": "item",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "cat",
                "type": "phrase_prefix",
                "fields": [
                    "label",
                    "body"
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "script": {
                "script": "if (_index == \"animals\") {return true;} else {return false}
            }
        },
        "from": 0,
        "size": 8
    }
}
```

Obviously I'd like to do more in this filter than just exclude items from a certain index, this is simply an example.

Comment: which version of elasticsearch ?

Comment: 2.1.1 currently, but possible to upgrade if needed?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to combine several [indices query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-indices-query.html) to solve this task.

Comment: `indices query` is deprecated in 5.0. But you can filter on `_index` field just like any other field.  `{"term": {"_index": "animals"}}`